# How can I debug/monitor Emacs to find out why it's using so much memory?

Tags: 10.04, debug, emacs

I'm using GNU Emacs 23.1.50.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.18.0) and start my Emacs session inside GNU screen.

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 10.04 and the version of `emacs-snapshot` there I encounter some problems. Sometimes Emacs hogs all RAM plus the same amount of swap space (2+2GB) and also eats all CPU time. When I send the process a SIGTERM the process stops eating CPU time, but the huge allocated amount of memory stays. Emacs itself doesn't take any key sequences. So usually I send the process a SIGKILL and it dies.

Now I want to find out where the bug (if there is one) is located and want to do some debugging. I can see no special reason for this behavior. Sometimes it starts after Emacs is freshly started, sometimes I can work a whole day without problems, sometimes it happens in between. So I'm looking for a kind of debugging or monitoring the process.

I tried `strace`, but this generates too much output. Strace output of an editing session could easily fill my whole hard drive. Running Emacs inside gdb would also not work, because if I remember correctly Ubuntu builds the software without debugging symbols. So do you have any advice on how I can find the (possible) bug? What would you suggest?

Comment: GNU Emacs 23.2 was released in May; if you are not satisfied with Ubuntu's default 23.1, good chances are that the bug has already been fixed upstream.

Comment: It seems that there are no Ubuntu packages for 23.2, so I'll have to check out CVS.

Comment: I strongly suspect that `emacs-snapshot` is lagging behind now and just plain `emacs` package will bring you more recent version. At least it did that to me a while back ago.

Comment: emacs-snapshot has version 23.1.50.1 and emacs 23.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this by accident. The problem was not emacs, but a malfunctioning GNOME keyring. When I start Emacs without the keyring daemon all is fine. So disabling it resolved my issue here.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the package **emacs-snapshot-dbg** might be of interest?

"This package contains the debugging symbols useful for debugging Emacs."

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I'm trying to save all content of Messages-buffer to a file and hope to find something useful:

```
(with-current-buffer "*Messages*" (auto-save-mode t))
```